# STM32F303 DMA throughput

Tags: arm, stm32, dma

It is maybe an easy question but I struggle to find the answer. What is the theoretical throughput of a DMA controller.

1. There are co conflicts between the core & DMA as all data (except those for DMA transfers are located in the CCMRAM)
2. Only one controller is transferring at the time

Comment: I have tried to tag it as cortex but unfortunately there is no tag : cortex. I though that it should be a quite popular topic.

Comment: For STM32F1 there's an [DMA application note](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/47/41/32/e8/6f/42/43/bd/CD00160362.pdf/files/CD00160362.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00160362.pdf): "AHB data transfers take 2 clock cycles, except for SRAM read-after-write accesses that
take 3 cycles. Data transfers to a peripheral through an APB bus takes 2 APB clock
cycles plus 2 AHB clock cycles dedicated to bus matrix arbitration and data
synchronization."

Comment: Yes of course I know this note but the results I get are lower. (I code bare register, so it is not the HAL or other library overhead)

Comment: Where are you transferring the data from and to?

Comment: double ADC -> RAM, RAM -> DAC. All variables used in the program (except DMA buffers of course) are placed into the CCMRAM and there are no conflicts between the core and DMA during the transfer.

Comment: How fast does the ADC produce data?